# Logging in Dynamic SQL

Tags: logging, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a Stored proc using dynamic sql. Is there any way to log the compilation errors occurring when  `SQLSTR1` compiles while calling the proc from Java. Or maybe log the variables involved.

```
SQLSTR1:= ' SELECT NVL(SUM(TOTAL_B),0) CURRENT_VAL,' || COL_NAME|| ' 
    FROM view1 WHERE(R_DATE  IS NULL OR R_DATE >:EOQ) 
    AND (LOCATION IN  (' || COMMA_FUNC(LOCATIO) || ') OR :LOCATIO = ''NULL'')
     GROUP BY ' || COL_NAME;  

    OPEN CURRENT_CURSOR FOR SQLSTR1 USING EOQ, LOCATIO;
```

The person managing the procs is not available and I need to do some debugging. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can display the values of bind variables by viewing v$sql_bind_capture: "V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE displays information on bind variables used by SQL cursors. Each row in the view contains information for one bind variable defined in a cursor." See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3044.htm#REFRN30310

Simple example:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE ct IS REF CURSOR;
    c ct;
    q VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    q := 'SELECT * FROM dual WHERE dummy = :EOQ OR dummy = :LOCATIO';
    OPEN c FOR q USING 'X', 'Y';
    CLOSE c;
END;
/

SELECT
     sql_id
    ,name
    ,value_string
    ,TO_CHAR(last_captured, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM v$sql_bind_capture
WHERE NAME IN (':EOQ', ':LOCATIO');
--
a2vmmmcumuv5v   :EOQ       X   14.11.2013 22:09:05
a2vmmmcumuv5v   :LOCATIO   Y   14.11.2013 22:09:05
                         ^^^^^
                       as expected
```